# Ember filter content and use controller method in filter

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, coffeescript, emblem.js

I have a page that I want to display different groups of users on. So far I am filtering the groups in the UsersController (ArrayController) with the following.

**users_controller.js.coffee:**

```
App.UsersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  content: []

  group1: (->
    @get('model').filterProperty('role', "group1")
  ).property('model.@each.type')

  group2: (->
    @get('model').filterProperty('role', "group2")
  ).property('model.@each.type')

  group3: (->
    @get('model').filterProperty('role', "group3")
  ).property('model.@each.type')
```

I am able to loop through each group in my users template with the following (using Emblem.js).

**users.emblem**

```
.role
  h3 Group 1
  each user in group1
    .segment
      = link-to 'user' user | #{user.first} #{user.last}
      p
        span #{user.shortStory}

.role
  h3 Group 2
  = each user in group2
    .segment
      = link-to 'user' user | #{user.first} #{user.last}
      p
        span #{user.shortStory}

.role
  h3 Group 3
  = each user in group3
    .segment
      = link-to 'user' user | #{user.first} #{user.last}
      p
        span #{user.shortStory}
```

Each user has a 'story' in its model. On the UserController I have a method called shortStory that shortens it into a 100 character or so snippet. (see the following code)

**user_controller.js.coffee**

```
App.UserController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  shortStory: (->
    short = @get('story').substring(0, 100)
    for i in short by - 1
      if i == " "
        break
      else
        short = short.slice( 0, -1)
    short
  ).property('story')
```

My problem is that I cannot get the shortStory to display for any of the users. I have tried many different syntaxes including the following:

```
span= user.shortStory
span #{user.shortStory}
span= shortStory
span= #{user.shortStory}
```

If anyone knows how I can access the UserController method while looping through a UsersController filter method in the view that would be great.

I am also open to other suggestions for filtering the data in the first place. I am still pretty fresh to ember.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to this question. I was able to add an itemController="user" to each each loop. This worked great.